# Why does my monitor take over 5 minutes to display anything after turning it on?

Tags: windows-7, video, display

When I turn on my monitor the screen is black and the power light on the monitor blinks every few seconds. This continues for 5-10 minutes and then either displays my desktop or a white screen.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and have an NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT graphics card.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes you are speaking of an LCD monitor...

Sounds like your monitor is dying (long returns from power-off, and all-white screens are bad news).

You may want to see if it behaves the same way on another computer;  If so, then it's done-for.

Otherwise, you'll want to get a hold of another monitor to try with your system (including a new cable) to see how it behaves.  If it's doing the same thing, it's not the monitor.

But I'd be willing to bet a doughnut or two it's the LCD, as we were fortunate enough to replace a couple/few dozen Samsung's under warranty due to this same problem over the year.  Eventually (if not very soon after problems started) the white screen would be all you got.

Comment: I have seen this behavior on bad video adapters as well, if you are using a video card and have an onboard adapter you can try, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I switched the monitors of my two computers and it had the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

This is a common problem with LCD monitor that have been used for a few years. Parts called capacitors in the power supply board start to fail and the power supply can't properly regulate the output voltages. The blinking power light is caused by the power supply board continuously resetting trying to stabilize and the white screen is when the back light portion of the power supply is working but the 5+ side that drives the video board is not. Most power supply boards can be easily repaired if you can do a little soldering. You will need to open the monitor to get to the power supply board and look for swollen or bulging capacitors. If you find them then replace them and your monitor should be as good as new. Here is a link to a web page that show what to look for and what to replace.
http://www.ccl-la.com/blog/index.php/capacitors/
Most boards can be repaired for less than $15 in parts so it's well worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the similar issue, took it to the nearest repair shop and got it fixed in one day. Took around 1000 rupees. Capacitor had to be replaced.
https://nishantrana.me/2021/07/03/fixed-monitor-taking-too-long-to-show-display/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try:

- Ensure the cable between the computer and monitor are connected properly at both ends
- Reinstall your video driver
- Reseat the graphics card inside the case
- Try a different cable (preferably one that's known to be working on another system)
- Try the monitor on a different computer with different cable

These will help you determine whether the problem is a corrupt video driver, a loose connection, a bad cable, a bad video card, or a bad monitor.